# 90s (?) short story: a society where everyone is eternally young except one man with the disease of age

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The whole world is filled by people whose completion of puberty is delayed, so they stay young forever. Their world is mostly just fun and play, with few people understanding science.

One man's treatment fails and he starts to age. They are horrified by his grey hair and wrinkles. He becomes isolated and mournful.  One of his friends or daughters realizes there is more to life, and starts talking to a scientist, and learning the basics of biology.

It's a fairly short story, from the 90s or earlier.

Comment: I've tagged `short-stories` with regards to your last sentence, but feel free to revert if you meant a very short novel or something :)

Comment: Norman Spinrad's "Deathwatch" has some of the same elements, but I don't think that's it.  An immortal couple gives birth to a son who ages normally.  You think that old person dying is a parent or even grandparent but it's their son.

Comment: It also sounds a lot like Damon Knight's "The Dying Man", though it is all that short (more like a novelette): In a far future, mankind has discovered the secret of immortality, and death is thought to be non-existent. But when the frustrated student Dio discovers he is mortal and death is approaching, he encounters, for the first time in his life, supreme happiness.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen you are correct, that is the right story. Thanks!

Comment: @fastmultiplication: Okay - I'll write it as an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Damon Knight's novelette "The Dying Man" (1957)**

In a far future, mankind has discovered the secret of immortality, and death is thought to be non-existent. But when the frustrated student Dio discovers he is mortal and death is approaching, he encounters, for the first time in his life, supreme happiness.

The story [can be read online](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/9781625791139/9781625791139___2.htm) at Baen Books.

It is also collected in the 1969 book *Three Novels**

[image]

Comment: That's a surprisingly modern looking book for 1869! +1

Comment: I'll edit that.  :-)